# Usage of ".... or: ..." in a title

Tags: punctuation, titles

I'm talking about "double titles" of the form "X or: Y". A well known example would be Kubrick's film

> Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb

I have two questions:

1. When is it recommended to use such a title? When I want to put the title and subtitle into one line?
2. Punctuation wise? Should it be "X or: Y", or "X, or: Y"?

Comment: When you're talking titles, you're talking whole-page formatting. First line is the title, next line is "or" in the middle, next line the subtitle. Punctuation ad lib; consult your designer. For inline quotation, you put a comma after the last letter of the title, then "or" and the subtitle (starting with a cap). The comma plus "or" is all you need.

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't such a title more likely to appear on posters, hand-bills and media casing? I see that prescription applies to the film script or screenplay but don't you think three lines, centred is unsuited to most media? 

I'd be tempted to agree about the punctuation, but both IBDM and Wikipedia use "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb"

To CSSSTUDENT I'd say, can you find a dozen other examples? If so, what do they have in common? If not, as John suggested, consult your own designer.